# Google Chart API and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, google-visualization

I write a C#-application at the moment. For my finance data, I want to use a bar chart. After I searched a lot on Google, the best way seems to be Google Chart API.

My problem is, that it should not be necessary that I have internet-access when I start my application. 
Is it possible to work with Google Chart API without internet-access? Or what is a good alternative for a bar chart in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google APIs work online only and you cannot consume them while offline.

about alternatives, the MS Chart control should be free, see how to use it from WPF or SL here:

[Microsoft Client Continuum in action: The Silverlight toolkit charts, running in WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2008/11/16/microsoft-client-continuum-in-action-the-silverlight-toolkit-charts-running-in-wpf.aspx)

for commercial level and feature rich controls, personally I love the XtraCharts from DevXpress, there are also others from Telerik and Software FX but XtraChart is really easy to use and powerful.

Answer (score 2):

As for native WPF charts you can definitely take a look at DevExpress WPF Chart control - [DXCharts](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Charting/)

They supports animation, end-user interaction and work pretty fast in my projects that handle financial data.